# Protractor Flake guidance needed to rerun failed test cases

Tags: javascript, protractor

Please correct my understanding for the below:

- I've installed protractor flake
- From the website we have 2 sets of
  code

**My assumption**

I'm pretty sure the B part needs to be given in `configuration.js` file
  of my protractor project but the A part where exactly should it be written.
  As a separate file should i write it and then require them in the spec file which i'm running.I need exact steps as to achieve the above

The usage section which starts with below:

```js
    **var protractorFlake = require('protractor-flake')
    // OR using es6 modules/typescript
    import protractorFlake = require('protractor-flake')**
    and ends with **process.exit(status)**
```

and the parsers section which starts with
`module.exports = { till return [...failedSpecs]`

Comment: I need a layman explanation for this no documented way to implement this in a step by step way is available hence i require your help .

Comment: you can refer this git repo. https://github.com/qualityshepherd/protractor-example

Comment: this example is good .https://github.com/nareshgumte/protractor_flake_eg

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation,

**Add dependency**

```
npm i protractor-flake

# or globally for easier cli usage 
npm i -g protractor-flake
```

**Running tests**

*Option 1: Via the CLI:*

```
# protractor-flake <protractor-flake-options> -- <options to be passed to protractor> 
protractor-flake --parser standard  --max-attempts=3 -- path/to/protractor.conf.js
```

Assuming that your `conf.js` file is in `root` directory.

> *Available command line options.*
>
> - **`color?: string | boolean`**
>
>   choose color from [here](https://github.com/chalk/ansi-styles#colors) or set `false` to disable coloring
>
>   Usage : `protractor-flake --parser standard  --color=magenta --max-attempts=3 -- conf.js`
> - **`protractorArgs?: string[]`**
> - **`protractorPath?: string`**: protractor location like this `'node_modules/.bin/protractor',`
>
>   Usage : `protractor-flake --parser standard --protractorPath=node_modules/.bin/protractor --max-attempts=3 -- conf.js`
> - **`parser?: string`**: the name of one of the included [parsers](https://github.com/NickTomlin/protractor-flake#parsers)
>
>   Usage : `protractor-flake --parser standard  --color=magenta --max-attempts=3 -- conf.js`
>
> You can refer other options from [here](https://github.com/NickTomlin/protractor-flake/blob/master/src/options.ts#L4-L15)

*Option 2: Programmatically*

Create file in your `root` directory as `flake` and copy below snippet.

`flake` is a node script that uses `protractor-flake` to re-run failed tests. Note
 that it reruns tests at the `file` level, so if one test fails, it will rerun all 
 the tests in that file.
Thanks Brian Ray to [this](https://github.com/qualityshepherd/protractor-example) repository

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 *
 * usage:
 * `./flake conf.js [other protractor args]`
 */

const protractorFlake = require('protractor-flake');
// skip first two passed args (node and self)
let protractorArgs = process.argv.splice(2);
console.log(protractorArgs);

protractorFlake({
    protractorPath: 'node_modules/.bin/protractor',
    maxAttempts: 3,
    parser: 'standard',
    nodeBin: 'node',
    protractorArgs: protractorArgs
}, (status, output) => {
    process.exit(status);
});
```

After creating this file, for avoiding permission error's just run `chmod +x ./flake`

To run your test cases

`./flake conf.js`

If you are keeping `specs` in a test suite, just pass after `conf.js`.

`./flake conf.js --suite smoke_test`

Before you are running, check these [`Caveats`](https://github.com/NickTomlin/protractor-flake#caveats)

Comment: @krishnaa-s, did you try this?

Comment: is flake a js file or a text file which i need to add

Comment: Step 1 I created a file called flake with the input you gave
step 2 under scripts added the "test":"./flake Configuration.js"
step 3 npm run test
result
flake isn't recognised as an internal or external command

Comment: `flake` is a node script that uses protractor-flake to re-run failed tests. I already mentioned that

Comment: did you run `chmod +x ./flake`?

Comment: Like this 
Steps to Integrate
Install
npm i -g  protractor-retry
Step 1: Require the Package ( Your Protractor Config )
var retry = require('protractor-retry');
Step 2: onPrepare ( Your Protractor Config )
onPrepare: function() {
  retry.onPrepare();
}

Step 3: onCleanUp ( Your Protractor Config )
onCleanUp = function(results) {
    retry.onCleanUp(results);
};