# Is there any way to rerun failed suite in protractor?

Tags: typescript, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm looking for a way to rerun **ONLY** failed suite using Protractor or external library. I have my e2e tests organised in suites in this way:

```
  suites: {
    partOfSystem1: 'path/to/folder/with/specs',
    partOfSystem2: 'path/to/folder/with/specs',
    partOfSystem3: 'path/to/folder/with/specs',
    ...
    partOfSystemN: 'path/to/folder/with/specs',
  },
```

I have quite a big amount of e2e specs and we have a CI, that's why I've built it in this way. I know, I should have each spec independent but with my amount of tests, it would take too long to run it. Each suite registers a new user and after suite is passed, a user is logged out.

### **What I want to achieve:**

Run full e2e tests (all suites), get information which suite went wrong and rerun it one more time.

Comment: Protractor Retry is what you want
https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-retry

Comment: @BenMohorc It's not working in my case. I'm getting errors: `E/launcher - spawn C:\Users\jakub\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor ENOENT
E/launcher - Error: spawn C:\Users\jakub\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:430:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17)
E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199`

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your conf file?

Comment: I've already found an issue source [link](https://github.com/yahoo/protractor-retry/issues/59)

Comment: Interesting, I did not even think of that as our entire test infrustructure is on linux. Good luck finding something that works

Answer (score 0):

You can check this library. **[Protractor Flake](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-flake)**

As per the documentation,

**Add dependency**

```
npm i protractor-flake

# or globally for easier cli usage 
npm i -g protractor-flake
```

**Running tests**

```
# protractor-flake <protractor-flake-options> -- <options to be passed to protractor> 
protractor-flake --parser standard  --max-attempts=3 -- path/to/protractor.conf.js
```

Already answered more details before. Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55474907/2372510)

Comment: This will work with a single test case but it won't with suites